# Slim with laravel pagination, always page 1

Tags: php, pagination, slim, laravel-pagination

I required `Illuminate/pagination` into my Slim 3 project

I've the following in my route:

```
$this->get('/traces', 'UserController:getTraces')->setName('user.traces');
```

In the getTraces method:

```
public function getTraces($req, $res)
{
    $loginRows = $this->db->table('login_history')->where('user_id', $_SESSION['user'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5);
    $loginRows->setPath($this->router->pathFor('user.traces'));

    $this->view->getEnvironment()->addGlobal('login_rows', $loginRows);

    return $this->view->render($res, 'user/traces.twig');
}
```

In my view (I'm using Twig):

```
{{ login_rows.render() | raw }}
```

So everything is working just fine and also the pagination html links, but even if I go to `?page=2` or any other page. It always display first page 1 with same rows. It says that it detect the page number but obviously it's wrong, is there a way I can set the page number manually or a fix if the problem is actually in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone interested, I just did that:

```
$loginRows = $this->db->table('login_history')->where('user_id', $_SESSION['user'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(5, ['*'], 'page', $req->getParam('page'));

$loginRows->setPath($this->router->pathFor('user.traces'));
```

This is fixed my problem, I'm sure there is a better solution but at least this works!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Eloquent's Paginator doesn't know how to extract the "page" parameter from Slim's router.  But you can give it a new function to help.  Here I've created a middleware that tells the Paginator how to find the "page" parameter.

```
<?php

/**
 * Tells the Eloquent Paginator how to get the current page
 */

namespace App\Middleware;

class Pagination {

    public function __invoke($request, $response, $next)
    {
        \Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator::currentPageResolver(function() use ($request) {
            return $request->getParam('page');
        });

        return $next($request, $response);
    }

}
```

Then when setting up the app, you can add this:

```
$app->add(new App\Middleware\Pagination);
```

Be aware that will be run for every page request (even those without pagination).  I doubt it's really a performance hit.  If concerned, you can apply it to specific routes.  Or call currentPageResolver() just before your query.